# having separate method for adding to datatable creates error (vs2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am making a library  program that can add and edit books in a datatable to do this I am trying to put the initialization and the adding to datatable in different methods but I can't seem to get it to work here is my code:

```
 class Book
{
    static DataTable libary = new DataTable();
    public static void Datatype()
    {
        //DataColumn Column;
        DataColumn ISBN = new DataColumn();
        //ISBN
        //library.Columns.Add("ISBN");
        ISBN.ColumnName = "ISBN";
        ISBN.DataType = typeof(int);
        ISBN.Unique = true;
        ISBN.AllowDBNull = false;
        ISBN.Caption = "ISBN";
        ISBN.DefaultValue = 00;
        libary.Columns.Add(ISBN);
        //Title
        DataColumn Title = new DataColumn();
        Title.ColumnName = "Title";
        Title.DataType = typeof(string);
        Title.Unique = false;
        Title.AllowDBNull = false;
        Title.Caption = "Book Tile";
        Title.DefaultValue = "--";
        libary.Columns.Add(Title);
        //Author
        DataColumn Author = new DataColumn();
        Author.ColumnName = "Author";
        Author.DataType = typeof(string);
        Author.Unique = false;
        Author.AllowDBNull = false;
        Author.Caption = "Author name";
        Author.DefaultValue = "--";
        libary.Columns.Add(Author);
        //Genre
        DataColumn Genre = new DataColumn();
        Genre.ColumnName = "Genre";
        Genre.DataType = typeof(string);
        Genre.Unique = false;
        Genre.AllowDBNull = false;
        Genre.Caption = "Book Genre";
        Genre.DefaultValue = "--";
        libary.Columns.Add(Genre);
        // OnLoan
        DataColumn OnLoan = new DataColumn();
        OnLoan.ColumnName = "OnLoan";
        OnLoan.Unique = false;
        OnLoan.DataType = typeof(Boolean);
        OnLoan.AllowDBNull = false;
        OnLoan.DefaultValue = false;
        OnLoan.Caption = "check to see if book is on loan";
        libary.Columns.Add(OnLoan);

    }
   /*internal static void add(DataTable libery)
    {

            DataRow Row;
            Row = libery.NewRow();
            //askes user for ISBN number and then adds to datatable
            int ISBN = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Row["ISBN"] = ISBN;
            // askes user for book title 
            string Title = Console.ReadLine();
            Row["Title"] = Title;
            DataRow row = libery.Rows[0];
            Console.WriteLine(row["ISBN"]);
            Console.ReadKey();

    }*/

    internal static void add(DataTable libary)
   {
       Console.Clear();
       Console.WriteLine("input ISBN number:");
       //DataTable libary = new DataTable();
       DataRow Row;
       Row = libary.NewRow();
       //askes user for ISBN number and then adds to datatable
       string ISBN = Console.ReadLine();
       Int16 ISBN_con = Convert.ToInt16(ISBN);            
       Row["ISBN"] = ISBN_con;
       libary.ImportRow(Row);
       // askes user for book title 
       string Title = Console.ReadLine();
       Row["Title"] = Title;
       libary.ImportRow(Row);
       DataRow row = libary.Rows[0];
       Console.WriteLine(row["ISBN"]);
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   internal static void view(DataTable libary)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        foreach (DataColumn column in libary.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write("Coloum: ");
            Console.Write(column.ColumnName);
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here is the error message: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll 
 Additional information: Column 'ISBN' does not belong to table

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Where does the error originate? how does your calling code look? - how do you call "add"? - because it uses the input variable "library" and not the class property "libary"

Comment: Note that your `ImportRow()` call doesn't add anything to the table, because as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.110).aspx) detached rows are not added by this method. You should use `library.Rows.Add()` instead.